# Import from parent directory node-sass

Tags: css, node.js, sass, compass-sass

I am using node-sass to mock my CDN builds and I am converting my CSS to
a modular Sass design. Basically my setup involves brand sites overwriting
the common styles.

I want to do something like this in the brand folder

```
@import "../common/global-config";
@import "brand-config";
@import "../common/common";

// brand specific styles here
```

this file would live at `/css/brand-name/brand.scss`

the other files would live `in /css/common/_common.scss`

my node-sass setup looks something like this

```
function compileSassFile(includes, path, callback) {
  if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
    return null;
  }

  var css = sass.renderSync({
      file: path,
      success: callback,
      outputStyle: 'expanded',
      includePaths: includes
  });

  return css;
}

// bundlePath = 'css', dirName = '/brand-name'
compileSassFile([path.join(bundlePath), path.join(bundlePath, 'common'), path.join(bundlePath, dirName)], path.join.apply(bundlePath, [dirName, 'brand.scss']));
```